# org.apache.catalina.startup.Embedded class not found in Apache tomcat 8

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, zk

I am developing a ZK Web application. I Upgraded from tomcat 6 to 8. But in my old code am using 'org.apache.catalina.startup.Embedded' class but it is not present in tomcat 8. Where can I find the same class? If this class is deprecated then what is the alternative for this class in Tomcat 8?

Comment: The class you are using was deprecated in tomcat 7. Checking its javadoc, it says to use org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat instead.
So you should probably check to update your code.
 
Also this blog post talk about embedded web app on Tomcat8 : http://www.jofre.de/?p=1227

Comment: thanks. It really helped. But in 'Embedded' class have functions to configure engine,host, connector and context. But these functions are changed in 'Tomcat' and some of the functions are not available. Is  there any document available to describes transition from 'Embedded' to 'Tomcat'  class?